# Enable public access to a specific page of RoR app with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to enable public access to a specific page of my rails app without authentification (tournaments#index). Authentification is required in my application_controller.rb with devise here :

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :pages_controller_or_contacts_controller?
```

I saw this syntax to achieve this:

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
```

but this is at a specific controller level and thus specifies only the action. In my case I need to specify the controller and the action because I am at the application_controller level

How can make the view related to my tournaments_controller and index action publicly accessible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the desired functionality if you add `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :index` to `tournaments_controller.rb`.